# Jetpack gallery shortcode with slideshow

Tags: shortcode, plugin-jetpack, slideshow

Images which  are coming from [gallery type="slideshow" ids="1311812,1311814,1311815"] not in lazy load . I am using a3 Lazy Load plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/a3-lazy-load/

Comment: I don't know Jetpack gallery but most lazy load plugins only work with images that are in the HTML, so i guess the gallery populates itself separately after the page has loaded? You'd need to change the Jetpack behaviour I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Some solution for it given by a3 plugin

JETPACK SITE ACCELERATOR (PHOTON)
This is an option that you turn on as the Jetpack Accelerator (Photon CDN images) has its own lazy load feature that needs to be OFF first to be able use a3 Lazy Load as your lazy Load engine. Some users prefer to use a3 Lazy Load as it applies Lazy Load to videos and iframes as well as images.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/a3-lazy-load/